# How work network paths in C#?

Tags: c#, path, xmldocument, verbatim-string

I'm having a doubt about this

I tried to save a xmlDocument in a network device folder, not mapping.

Where:

```
config.plc.Path ="\\IpAdress\\folder\\";

doc.Save(config.plc.Path + "file.xml");
```

It was throwing an exception, and I just fixed it using the '@'

```
doc.Save(@config.plc.Path + "file.xml");
```

When I add the parameter as verbatim string with @, it gets like this:

```
config.plc.Path ="\\\\IpAdress\\\\folder\\\\";
```

is the first time I see a path like this, with

```
\\\\
```

can someone help me to understand this?

Comment: Network paths start with \\ symbol, in c# when you want to write that you need to use verbatim string or just escape backslashes. If you escape backslashes you will get \\\\

Comment: So, if I don't add @, c# gets it like a backslash?

Comment: You have to use a proper UNC path.  It is `"\\\\machname\\share\\dir\\file.ext"`.  Or `@"\\machname\share\dir\file.ext"`.  Do avoid an IP-address, they change.

Comment: @Ferus7 yes, you need to escape some characters in string. see the answer bellow for explanation

Comment: I read the static IP Address from an xml, Thank you all, now I understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, \\ is just an escape sequence for \. @ (Verbatim String) has to be used to avoid this

Comment: I think i understand it, if I don't use a verbatim, the path will start with \ instead of \\ and it will refer to C: